# How to Play & Unmute Html Video that comes into View

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video

I am attempting to play & unmute html videos as they come into view. The code below ⬇, is what I use to play the videos when the come into view currently.

```
// is visible function
function isVisible(elem) {
  if (!(elem instanceof Element)) throw Error('DomUtil: elem is not an element.');
  const style = getComputedStyle(elem);
  if (style.display === 'none') return false;
  if (style.visibility !== 'visible') return false;
  if (style.opacity < 0.1) return false;
  if (elem.offsetWidth + elem.offsetHeight + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height +
      elem.getBoundingClientRect().width === 0) {
      return false;
  }
  const elemCenter   = {
      x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left + elem.offsetWidth / 2,
      y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.offsetHeight / 2
  };
  if (elemCenter.x < 0) return false;
  if (elemCenter.x > (document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth)) return false;
  if (elemCenter.y < 0) return false;
  if (elemCenter.y > (document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight)) return false;
  let pointContainer = document.elementFromPoint(elemCenter.x, elemCenter.y);
  do {
      if (pointContainer === elem) return true;
  } while (pointContainer = pointContainer.parentNode);
  return false;
}

// on window load start checking on scroll 
window.onload = function() {
  var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video")
  function checkScroll() {
      for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
          var video = videos[i];
          if(isVisible(video)){
            video.play();
video.muted = !video.muted;
                      }else{
            video.pause();
           }
      }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
  window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);

}
```

I've tried adding `video.muted = !video.muted;`  directly under `video.play();` and it seems to work. However I noticed when the user scrolls the video continuously (mutes & unmutes) unless the user is not scrolling while in view of the video. In addition, if the user pauses the video and scrolls the slightest while the video is still in view, the video will resume playback.

Comment: @AlberEinstein Hey, you previously helped me. so I tagged you in the comments. I was wondering if you are willing to provide feedback, regarding a solution to this question?

Comment: What you mean I don't understand your question. Can you clarify it in details :)

Comment: @AlbertEinstein I need for the JS code snippet in the question to be able to play and “unmute” videos as they come into view. Is this possible?

Comment: If you manage to detect the video that is in viewport then you can but its complex.